# c# Convert.ToBase64(String) with no pluses

Tags: c#, url, base64

I have a string which I need to convert to base64.
The default convert

`byte[] cipherbytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainbytes, false);`

`return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes);`

I get a string which has '+' like  "pURT+TFG=" and is converted to a space when sent as a get, so I can't compare to the original.

Comment: You would need to html encode the string after

Comment: @BugFinder URL encode, rather than HTML encode when using in a web request.

Comment: Fair point.. (havent had any food or caffine yet this morning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it sounds as a bad idea to send large sets of bytes in the query string. Short byte arrays should be fine. Make sure if this is what you need.

Second, you have to URL encode your base64 encoded string, by calling `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `WebUtility.UrlEncode` (prefer the latter):

```
byte[] cipherbytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainbytes, false);

return WebUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes));
```

Comment: Only found WebUtility.HtmlEncode and returns **Plus** signs

Comment: Of course. That is what `HtmlEncode` does. That's why I said to use `UrlEncode`. Duh.

Comment: A workaround (which is OK for my purpose, but doesn't answer the question) is to Replace all '+' with "P' or any other character

Comment: Why would you workaround it if you can simply use the right method?

Comment: The answer is correct, and might help me in the future, but since I'm saving to the DB as returned, and comparing when received, it doesn't suit my purposes. Using it in the Body with a POST with no changes enables me to compare.
Thanks for all your help